# Trying to get variable from WP table and toggle its value

Tags: wpdb

I have a query setup in a function to grab the payment status from a table in wordpress using a search string.
It will usually be 'Completed' (returned from paypal IPN).
All i'm trying to do is allow a local option to change the value string to another value and back again.
This is what i have so far:

```
 <!---TOGGLE PAYMENT STATUS--->

<?php function toggle_payment_status ()
        { 
           
 global $wpdb;
 $ipn_tables = $wpdb->prefix ."ipn_data_tbl";
 $searchIP = $_POST["searchIP"];
 
 $StatusCheck = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payment_status FROM {$ipn_tables} WHERE serial_no = %s "),$searchIP);


  if ($StatusCheck = "Completed")   {
       $StatusCheck = "Refunded";
      } 
  
  else if ($StatusCheck = "Refunded")    {
      $StatusCheck = "Completed";
      }
                             
      $wpdb->update($ipn_tables, array(
          'payment_status' => $StatusCheck
                             ) , array(
            'serial_no' => $searchIP,
    ));
 }
```

When i run it the completed string changes to Refunded. A check in the Database shows the change. Great. So the $statuscheck should be this new 'changed' value of Refunded...but i don't understand why the if statements are failing.
I did try elseif but not working either.
Could someone steer Mr dumbo in the right direction and explain what i did wrong?
Too much coffee & late nights hasn't help. Thank you.

Comment: If this is not a typo only in the question then in the "**IF**" condition you should replace `=` with `==` and second `if` with `else if`.

Comment: Hello, 
forgot to say i tried that too. the = in $StatusCheck = "Refunded"; is setting the Status check to Refunded correct? But if i use 
if ($StatusCheck == "Completed")   { the value is emplty in DB (null?) so i tried that already...if that's what you mean?

Comment: `if ($StatusCheck == "Completed") { $StatusCheck = "Refunded"; } else if ($StatusCheck == "Refunded") { $StatusCheck = "Completed"; }`. If this code sets DB column to `NULL`, it means that the query returns no results. Check that `$_POST["searchIP"]` is set and valid before using it in query.

Comment: `code` <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit4']) && !empty($_POST['submit4'])) {
   $searchIP = $_POST["searchIP"];
 
         toggle_payment_status ();
          
       
              }else{
        
 }?>'code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues I see in your code:

1. The `$searchIP` is actually outside of the `$wpdb->prepare()`: (I didn't use the full query so that you'd see the issue clearer)

   ```php
   $StatusCheck = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payment_status ..."),$searchIP);
   ```

   So you should correct that, like so: (reindented for clarity)

   ```php
   $StatusCheck = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
       SELECT payment_status FROM {$ipn_tables}
       WHERE serial_no = %s
   ", $searchIP ) );
   ```
2. Your `if` should use the equality operator (`==` or `===`) and not the basic assignment operator (`=`).

   So for examples, use `if ($StatusCheck == "Completed")` and `if ($StatusCheck == "Refunded")` instead of what you currently have in your code.

Comment: Thank you Sally :) Stupid me. That did it. It might be obvious but sometimes you get so fixed on another area (like the "if" statements and didn't look up at that.
Thank you. I did have the compare originally ( == ) but fixated on that and not my  prepare. I'll  "prepare" myself better next time LOL and thanks also @nmr

Comment: You're very welcome, and I'm glad I could help. :)